# How to deal with questions/answers where users just improvise to keep their profile status

Tags: discussion

How to deal with the following type of behavior:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096566/angular-7-project-got-a-some-error-in-angular-material?noredirect=1#comment96937490_55096566 (Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot])

- The type of error is kind of basic.
- User didn't put in a lot of effort to check himself.
- I provide him with the exact pointer into what might be wrong (since figuring out the exact command/library is way out of proportion to the solution (time-wise).
- He claims it works after that.
- I added the comment as answer and ask him the accept.
- User deletes the comment that it works and adds in the exact command in the comments.
- I downvote his question since he it is poor quality and no research has been done.
- User just deletes the question all-together (for whatever reason)

I have a lot of behavior like this. Frustrating if you try to improve your profile. There are already not many 'new topics/answers' left. I can accept that my answer is not always 100%, but this is just plain stupid. And yes, I answered out of free will... But there is a line of correctness and its not like I want to waste my time over this.

Comment: Ok. I ventilated what I needed to ventilate.   I've learned the lesson and when take this as something positive :) thanks all

Comment: Is the question common enought so we can make cannoncical question out of it? without the need to specify one particular build or Sub libairy? Is there any existing duplicate that cover your answer and the code Op used to solved the issue? If the answer to previous question are 'Yes, can build a better/easier to find question' and 'No exting dupe'. It could be rewrite into a 'cannonical question'.

Comment: It's an hard task, the new question may never leave your notepad because you failed to match some quality standard. I have 20+ questions in my Notepad that are generalisation of poor deleted question. If the question is worthy, maybe you can try to repost it. meta is not a sandbox but for building cannonical it can be use to validate specifc point.

Comment: Notably, had your answer been up-voted or accepted before the OP tried to delete the question, it wouldn't have been possible to delete it.

Comment: @Lundin don't know how to answer to this.  I provided the answer in 5 min or so. after half an hour everything was gone.  I guess a combination of no interest in the question, no time to react and people who have learned not to react on such type of questions.  Anyway, I got smarter. thats all I can say

Comment: @jcuypers What it means is, you didn't lose any rep, just the effort of posting an answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The issue is:

> His question ... is poor quality and no research has been done

Don't answer questions like that! Instead, vote to close, and possibly downvote.

If you do answer bad questions, you certainly risk the question getting downvoted and deleted. That's not something that can or should change.

Comment: it is wrong that the user himself closes the question because he is not willing to accept the downvotes and not willing to give the credit.  i dont have a problem of closing bad questions in general.  anyway i see where this is going already

Comment: @jcuypers You can't expect someone that clearly ignores our rules and standards when asking the question to nicely keep to the rules when handling an answer. This just happens. A lot. The only way to avoid it is to only answer questions that are at least half decent.

Comment: ok i agree.  fact is there is little left for new users here i'm afraid.

Comment: @jcuypers What makes it harder for a new user to post answers to decent questions than it is to old SO hands?

Comment: @yivi. without dragging this issue.  I guess, its like an encyclopedia.  all the information is already there. nobody opens it to actually check.  everyone posts the same questions.  I guess there are not many new things that need to be/can be added to an encyclopedia and the original authors keep getting rep. on original contributions and new contributions get closed by the comittee that handles new content.    exagerated, but thats a good analogy.

Comment: @jcuypers And yet, our top contributors **keep posting answers every day**. I guess our encyclopedia is not quite done yet. No "mission accomplished" banner yet. If stablished users can post new answers to decent questions every day, why couldn't a new user do the same?

Comment: @jcuypers new information becomes available requiring new answers and maybe even questions. Some answers that work now may not work in a few years and some new features may make a different answer easier or faster. And remember, ti bigger the encyclopedia, the more effort is required in upkeep.

Comment: @yivi  ok understood. i'll see how i can make a positive daily contribution.

Answer (score 4):

*When you can't change a situation that you don't like, change your behavior not to let that situation affect you, or even not to end up in a similar one again.*

As @Erik A has mentioned, you should not try to answer low-quality questions, and if you are willing to answer them, be prepared for situations where users could delete them, or when questions like that will be closed.

In my first days of Stack Overflow, I used to ask low-quality questions, and delete them when I've seen the response from the community. That behavior is pretty common among new users. Most of the times, when answering a question of a newcomer to SO, he/she may even not mark as an answer (because he/she does not know how and is not interested to do so) and you will end up with a good answer that has no *reward*.

Instead of expecting an upvote, or even getting the question closed, you should ask yourself why are you answering questions here. Is it because you want a great reputation with shiny badges? Or is it because you just want to help the others? I can relate that it is discouraging to see people not appreciating your efforts and not following the rules here, but you can see the bright side, that a part of the newcomers start to learn about Stack Overflow and how the Stack Exchange works, and they end up as part of the community for which you had a contribution.

Comment: Its not that i dont understand or accept. everyone is a bit right.  like you said. just frustrating.  I am hobby programmer who want to get into real programming job. so for me yes. i need some way to build my credibility.  whether or not this is with these kind of questions... we agree :)

Comment: @jcuypers, As an aside, your answer reads more like a comment. A complete answer would provide clear rationale, *how* to proceed with the steps you outline, rather than just a vague statement "seems to me...". Good grammar (capitalizing the first word of sentences) does not diminish credibility, while poor grammar is sure to reduce your credibility.

Comment: Like I said: the time to pinpoint the exact problem would require me to replicate the full issue.  I provide him with the exact pointer into what might be wrong (since figuring out the exact command/library is way out of proportion to the solution (time-wise).  he got what he needed, as to look where he needed to put some effort in the first place.   I think pointing a non native speaker on how he could have formulated his humble response to a senior contributor who should know better in the first place, is a bit far fetched.

Comment: The reason why I am taking this tone is because you get downvoted for everything that is not delivered as a spoon-fed answer (with a golden spoon). sorry, but it stops somewhere. certainly if every time you get crappy behavior on top of it.  and btw I dare you to formulate the correct command based on the above. really. sometimes

Comment: and as a reponse to an initial question posted:   what do you want to be the outcome of your question.    well easy.  if there could be some kind of rep. punishment  that could be given (by consesus of x members) to such an associal posting that would lead us to something constructive instead of talking about my language level, which all in all is acceptable. there is no punishment / too little punishment for incorrect / associal / non-constructive behavior.

Comment: @jcuypers not sure about "building my credibility", but you might be interested in [Should I include information about my reputation on professionally-relevant Stack Exchange (or other Q&A) sites on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/308)

Comment: @AndrewT. thank you. Time will tell I guess.  My aim is to show that I have at least some understanding of the topics I claim to understand based on the tags I answer.  on almost every application they ask (mandatory) github/SO handles.

Answer (score -4):

I just came back to see if everyone is still patting everyone's back for stupidity and how great everything is, while valid points are blatantly ignored and honed.  anyway, you can downvote however you like, the crux (language proficiency rules apparently)  is that people are still copying comments as answers seconds  one is posting them,  playing the system for their own benefit in however way and ruining the experience for others.  the countermeasures are next to useless and are non-enforcable.   what individuals can do against what others can undo (by votes) is way out of proportion.   Anyway, I can guess the answers, so save your time.  this is meant as something constructive.   The abuse that i'm talking about is rampant and omni-present and makes this site... well... less ok than it could be.   its not something about me not getting my 2 points.

Comment: _everyone is still patting everyone's back for stupidity_ Real constructive. Maybe it's better you take a break from the site, since you are feeling all this bitterness about how the site and its community works?

Comment: It's called reality